# Python tkinter interface with cx_freeze looks very different (broken) on some computers

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

I created a tkinter interface with python3.4 and freezed it with cx_freeze and a setup.py file.
When starting the program on my computer (win8.1 x64), two VMs on my computer (Win2k8 R2 x64 and Win7 Enterprise x64) and two other notebooks (one Win8.1, one Win7) it looks just as I want.

But on three other notebooks (Win7, Win7, Win7) the interface looks so different that its damaged.
(See screenshots below).

At first it seems as it is a Win7 Problem but please notice, that I have two Win7 systems, where the interface looks fine.

Help is very appreciated!

I use the grid geometry manager for the layout.
This is how I implemented this widgets:

```
tk.Label(master, text='File', width=15).grid(row=0, column=2)
tk.Label(master, text='Delimiter ( , ; \\t space )',
         width=15).grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=5)

tk.Label(master, text='Glam', width=15).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(master, text='net.loc', width=15).grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Label(master, text='net.dev', width=15).grid(row=3, column=0)
tk.Label(master, text='Output Folder', width=15).grid(row=4, column=0)

self.delimiter1 = tk.Entry(master, width=20)
self.delimiter1.grid(row=1, column=1)

self.delimiter2 = tk.Entry(master, width=20)
self.delimiter2.grid(row=2, column=1)

self.delimiter3 = tk.Entry(master, width=20)
self.delimiter3.grid(row=3, column=1)

self.glamPath = tk.Entry(master, width=75)
self.glamPath.grid(row=1, column=2)

self.locationPath = tk.Entry(master, width=75)
self.locationPath.grid(row=2, column=2)

self.devicesPath = tk.Entry(master, width=75)
self.devicesPath.grid(row=3, column=2)

self.outputPath = tk.Entry(master, width=96)
self.outputPath.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

b1 = tk.Button(master, text='Open', width=15,
               command=lambda: self.openCallback(1))
b1.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5)

b2 = tk.Button(master, text='Open', width=15,
               command=lambda: self.openCallback(2))
b2.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5)

b3 = tk.Button(master, text='Open', width=15,
               command=lambda: self.openCallback(3))
b3.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5)

b4 = tk.Button(master, text='Select', width=15,
               command=lambda: self.openCallback(4))
b4.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=5)
```

[image: Correct]
Here you see the buttons on the right and bottom are correct.

[image: Wrong]
Here you see the buttons aren't displayed...

Comment: Do you force the size of the window to be a specific width and height? It looks like it's just using a different,larger font on the "broken" systems. Maybe these systems don't have the right font installed, or the system is returning the wrong DPI information so the fonts are scaled bigger. If you force the GUI to a particular size, these two combined might cause some widgets to be invisible.

Comment: Yes I do. In particular i use this to position the window in the screen center. When I get the size with
`self.update()
width = self.winfo_width()`
it works. But is there a way to exactly know why this happens? I don't understand why my win7 vm without any additional instalaltions but the c++ redistributable to make cx_freeze work shows it the way I want, but others show it different

Comment: It could be a number of things. It might be using the right font, but windows might be giving tkinter the wrong DPI information (which it might be getting from the monitor or monitor driver itself). It could be that it's a different font and one system has it and one doesn't. If you aren't setting the font family explicitly, maybe on one system the user has picked a different default font or font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on answers to questions in the comments, it appears that the problem is two-fold:

1. the system with the chopped-off buttons is using a larger font, and
2. your application uses a fixed GUI size and isn't prepared to handle a larger font

Part of the solution is to *not* force the GUI to a specific size. Let tkinter do what it does best and resize the widgets to accommodate whatever font the user has chosen.

As to why these two systems are using different fonts, it could be for several reasons. The most obvious might be that the user account with the larger font has simply picked a larger default font in the control panel. Another problem could be that both systems are using the same font, but tkinter is drawing them differently. Tkinter uses DPI information it gets from the system to draw fonts, and if this information is incorrect it will draw fonts slightly larger or smaller than they should be (eg: if it thinks the display has a DPI of 100 when it actually has a DPI of 80).

Another reason might be as simple as one system having a font that the other does not. If both systems have the exact same version of OS, this is unlikely since they should each get the standard set.

There are probably other reasons as well that I'm not thinking of. Tkinter is actually quite good at handling this, as long you let it decide how big widgets should be. If you can do that, then your application should display and function correctly, even if it is literally a little larger or smaller on the screen as measured by a ruler. If you use `place` a lot, or force the window to be a specific pixel size, you're going to have to manually account for different font sizes.